# SQL Server installation required for deploying a WPF application

Tags: sql-server, wpf, deployment

I am deploying WPF application built with Entity Framework 6.0 and SQL Server 2008. Do I need to install SQL Server 2008 on the client machine to use the application or not? I am asking this because Application will connect to database hosted on the server machine

Answer (score 3):

No, SQL Server does not need to be on the same machine as the application.

Comment: not asking about that database, `SQL Server` needs to be installed or not?